# creating web service proxy and deleting WSDL file issue

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wsdl

i just need to know that after creating web service proxy if i delete wsdl file then is there will be any problem for creating web service class related instance?

so guide what i need to do after deleting wsdl file from VS2010 IDE as a result there will be no problem to call web service.

my first question was about web service(ASMX) file. so my question is still same but what i need to do in case WCF service. because there is also wsdl file generate after creating proxy. if i delete wsdl file in this case also so how could i make a call to wcf service.

please explain in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a Service Reference, Visual Studio creates a file called `Reference.svcmap` inside the `Service References/<service name>/` folder, which describes your service.  It contains links to the various metadata sources and the configuration options that you used when creating the Service Reference ("Configure Service Reference" from the context menu).

This `Reference.svcmap` is the only file that you must not delete.  When you right-click your Service Reference and select "Update Service Reference" from the context menu, Visual Studio will re-download all the required metadata from their upstream sources, re-create the client proxy and update your `app.config` file.

From the `Service References/<service name>` directory, the client proxy `Reference.cs` is the only file that's actually used when compiling your client app (so you shouldn't delete this either, though Visual Studio will automatically re-generate it for you) - none of these files are used at runtime.

This article also explains what all these files are about:
http://scottseely.com/2009/01/26/misunderstood-add-service-reference/

Comment: tell me clearly which file i should not delete. what is the name and extension of that file.

Comment: r u talking about wcf or classic web service asmx. in case of asmx no file is generated called svcmap rather Reference.map is gnerated.

Comment: one very important question when we work with asmx web service then when we create web service instance there we can mention our web service url to url property. so i just need to know this url property is available in case of WCF.

Comment: Oh, I was talking about WCF - haven't really used asmx very much

Answer (score 1):

`WSDL` file is describes your service operations. In order to generate client Proxies, WSDL file is used.

After you finished creating client proxy, you do not need WSDL file anymore. In fact, it is a good practice to delete or restricting access to WSDL file is a good practice in terms of security.

So you will not need WSDL file, unless you make changes to the service, such as adding a new operation or deleting an existing one. In this case, WSDL file is need to update the client again.

Comment: one very important question when we work with asmx web service then when we create web service instance there we can mention our web service url to url property. so i just need to know this url property is available in case of WCF.